# How can i detect when a button is tapped using Jqtouch?

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I have a problem with my web app. I use Jqtouch to develop it but I don't know how to detect when a button is tapped. This is part of my code and it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<ul class="edit rounded" id="campi" name="campi"> 
    <li><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" id="some_name" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" /></li> 
    <li><input type="password" name="name" placeholder="Password" id="some_name" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" /></li> 
</ul>                        

<a id="submit" name="submit" class="submit">Accedi</a>
```

Jquery code ( not working ) :

```
$("#submit").tap( function() {
    alert('Test');
});
```

Please help me fix. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using a framework? Even though you have a web app you can still handle gestures including taps with UIGestureRecognizer.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. i'm not developing an app whit xcode, i'm developing it whit JQtouch, a framework based on jQuery ( Based on javascript ). Thanks!

Comment: @rohit Thanks, but it doesn't do anything even if i changed it :(

Comment: Do you know how to program using Objective-C? I'm just curious why you wouldn't use it, it's very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$("#submit").click(function (){ alert('Test'); });`. Tap is a kind of click on any dom element iphone.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do anything even if i changed it :(